# Hide text box or another input field when drop down selected yii2 framework

Tags: php, yii2

Im wondering. In yii2 framework, is there any possible ways to hide or disable another input field such as text box without using javascript?

**Updated**

> Scenario example

In the picture below, when i select `Half Day` at `Leave Type` drop down list, that `End Date` field will be hidden.[image]

How can it be done without using jquery or javascript? Is that possible?

Comment: I think you should use Pjax. But anyway Pjax it's Yii2 widget, which uses JavaScript in common for sending requests.

Comment: Alright sir, i'll try read and explore about pjax. Btw sir, im not very clear about jquery and javascript because im quite new in php and this framework. Where do i have to call the function and declare the script?

Comment: You need to use jQuery to toggle end date.

Comment: i need to place the jquery inside the `form.php` right?

Comment: Yes, In form, onchange of leave type toggle end date picker.

Comment: why would you take  longer path to do something when the short path is available ?

Comment: @InsaneSkull Alright sir, thank you

Comment: @MuhammadOmerAslam what do you mean sir? is there any simple and short way to do that?

Answer (score 0):

In common, you need to store somewhere information "Does dropdown item was selected?". While rendering the page, in your `view.php` file something will be like:

```php
<!-- HTML code --->
<? if(!$_SESSION['checked']): ?>
    <input type="text" name="fieldName" \>
<? endif ?>
<!-- HTML code --->
```

Comment: why do we need to put it inside the `view.php` sir?

Comment: If you provide the situation where this will be used, i will add more examples. In the main it do while rendering the page.

Comment: In different way you may use Pjax.